Hashcat giving error when trying to decrypt MD5 with Salt- Token length exception
Trying to use Hashcat to decrypt a salted MD5.
Really frustrating me. Browsed through alot of the forums both for Stack Overflow and hashcat forums but couldn't find more than the linking of this page: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes, which I'm almost certain I am following for my format.
Tried using the example ones, they worked.
Salt- <1755.1.5f403625.BcWGgpKzUPRC8vscWn0wuA==@vps-7e2f5a72>
MD5- 4ddd4137b84ff2db7291b568289717f0
Format in the .txt: 1755.1.5f403625.BcWGgpKzUPRC8vscWn0wuA==@vps7e2f5a72:4ddd4137b84ff2db7291b568289717f0
Command ran- hashcat -a 0 -m 20 pass.txt rockyou.txt
Expected it to work, instead receiving -
Token length exception: 1/1 hashes
This error happens if the wrong hash type is specified, if the hashes are
malformed, or if input is otherwise not as expected (for example, if the
--username option is used but no username is present)
I understand I'm for sure messing up somewhere but I've tried using the -m 10 option and switching the order, doing rockyou first, etc.
Crack
